# When exactly does git prune objects: why is "git gc" not removing commits?

Tags: git, git-gc

I'm working on a git course and wanted to mention that lost refs are not really lost until running `git gc`. But verifying this, I found out that this is not the case. Even after running `git gc --prune=all --aggressive` the lost refs are still there.

Clearly I misunderstood something. And before saying something incorrect in the course, I want to get my facts straight! Here is an example script illustrates the effect:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 git init

 # add 10 dummy commits
 for i in {1..10}; do
     date > foo.txt
     git add foo.txt
     git commit -m "bump" foo.txt
     sleep 1
 done;

 CURRENT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
 echo HEAD before reset: ${CURRENT}

 # rewind
 git reset --hard HEAD~5

 # add another 10 commits
 for i in {1..10}; do
     date > foo.txt
     git add foo.txt
     git commit -m "bump" foo.txt
     sleep 1
 done;
```

This script will add 10 dummy commits, reset to 5 commits in the past and add another 10 commits. Just before resetting, it will print the hash of it's current HEAD.

I would *expect* to lose the object in `CURRENT` after running `git gc --prune=all`. Yet, I can still run `git show` on that hash.

I do understand that after running `git reset` and adding new commits, I have essentially created a new branch. But my original branch no longer has any reference, so it does not show up in `git log --all`. It also would not be pushed to any remote I suppose.

My understanding of `git gc` was that is removes those objects. This does not seem to be the case.

Why? And *when* exactly does `git gc` remove objects?

Comment: Your reflog still contains references to the commits you "deleted". Until those timeout or you explicitly expire them, they won't get pruned.

Comment: Interesting. I've had a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog and ran `git reflog --expire=all`. After which the object was *still* there. Next I ran another `gc` and it was still there. Even another `git gc --aggressive --prune=all` did not help.

Comment: You need `--expire=all --all`, or to run it on both `HEAD` (default) and `master`.  Or you can manually delete the specific entries (or see answer below).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For an object to be pruned, it must meet *two* criteria.  One is date/time related: it must have been created<sup>1</sup> long enough ago to be ripe for collection.  The "long enough ago" part is what you are setting with `--prune=all`: you're overriding the normal "at least two weeks old" setting.

The second criterion is where your experiment is going wrong.  To be pruned, the object must *also* be *unreachable*.  As [twalberg noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733131/when-exactly-does-git-prune-objects-why-is-git-gc-not-removing-commits#comment62937879_37733131), each of your ostensibly-abandoned commits (and hence their corresponding trees and blobs) is actually referenced, through Git's "reflog" entries.

There are two reflog entries for each such commit: one for `HEAD`, and one for the branch name to which `HEAD` itself referred at the time the commit was made (in this case, the reflog for `refs/heads/master`, i.e., branch `master`).  Each reflog entry has its own time-stamp, and `git gc` also expires reflog entries for you, although with a more complex set of rules than the simple "14 days" default for object expiry.<sup>2</sup>

Hence, `git gc` **could** first delete all reflog entries that are keeping the old object around, **then** prune the object.  It just is not happening here.

To view, or even delete, reflog entries manually, use `git reflog`.  Note that `git reflog` *displays* entries by running `git log` with the `-g` / `--walk-reflogs` option (plus some additional display formatting options).  You can run `git reflog --all --expire=all` to clear everything out, though this is a bludgeon when a scalpel may be more appropriate.  Use `--expire-unreachable` for a bit more selectivity.  For more about this, see [the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) and of course [the `git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).

---

<sup>1</sup>Some Unix-y file systems do not store file creation ("birth") time at all: the `st_ctime` field of a `stat` structure is the *inode change time*, not the creation time.  If there is a creation time, it is in `st_birthtime` or `st_birthtimespec`.<sup>3</sup>  However, every Git object is read-only, so the file's creation time is also its modification time.  Hence `st_mtime`, which *is* always available, gives the creation time for the object.

<sup>2</sup>The exact rules are described in [the `git gc` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html), but I think *By default, 30 days for unreachable commits and 90 days for reachable commits* is a decent summary.  The definition of *reachable* here is unusual, though: it means *reachable from the current value of the reference for which this reflog holds old values.*  That is, if we're looking at the reflog for `master`, we find the commit that `master` identifies (e.g., `1234567`), then see if each reflog entry for `master` (e.g., `master@{27}`) is reachable *from that particular commit* (`1234567` again).

<sup>3</sup>This particular name confusion is brought to you by the POSIX standardization folks. :-)  The `st_birthtimespec` field is a `struct timespec`, which records both seconds and nanoseconds.

Comment: Note that reflog entries are eventually garbage-collected too. As [the `git gc` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) says, the optional configuration variable `gc.reflogExpire` defaults to 90 days, and `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` defaults to 30 days. Reachable and unreachable entries in the reflog will be deleted if they are older than those variables when `git gc` is run.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane: right; I left that to the documentation links, but perhaps I should mention it in the answer directly?

Comment: Yes, I think it could be useful to address the title of the question more directly by saying that `git gc` will sometimes remove commits. That would also avoid suggesting that `git reflog` is the only command that deletes reflog entries. However, writing that into your answer isn't *that* important, given that readers can get the same information from these comments.

Comment: Do you know if the `prune` would delete also detached commits that are being referenced in commit messages? Or that reference (if it is interpreted as one) would makes them *reachable*?

Comment: @Kamafeather: commit message text is not scanned for hash IDs. If the hash ID appears in something that *is* scanned, the Git object will be retained, but if the hash ID appears only in a commit message, the object will be eligible for garbage collection.