# Reducing .git folder size for faster backup

Tags: git

I need to move all my local projects (mostly git), but I want to avoid to copy unnecessary files which can be recovered by a git pull. I want to clean all projects so that I don't need to copy local caches and build artifacts, but I want to keep decrypted secrets etc.

Which parts of my local copy of the git history can I delete so that I can keep the current head commit/branch and the current snapshot (maybe with local changes) which I can recover on the target system by a simple git pull?

Comment: Just throw away the invisible .git folder. You can clone from the remote later. Or don't move the project at all; _just_ clone from the remote.

Comment: When I delete the `.git` folder I need to search for the origin for each project. I don't want to use that old PC anymore so I need to move those files ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I would just write down the remote url for each of them, not move them, and just clone fresh on the new machine. You could have done it in the time since you posted the question. I don't see how this is a programming question.

Comment: This question is more or less about understanding the internals of git. Since git is a very common tool for programming this question should be on topic for SO. Technically I already tried to copy those files and it stuck multiple times (most likely some recursive softlinks in build caches) and most relevant for me I have already lots of secrets locally decrypted which I would need to decrypt again for lots of projects.

Comment: I found out why the copy process always hung up: It were the "ephemeral" directories for some linux flutter plugins. My workaround is to delete those directories before copy with `find /path/to/development/folder -type d -name ephemeral | xargs rm -rf`

Comment: You never even said there _was_ a problem with copying. This is a nonquestion.

Comment: This is why this was just a comment: Not related to my question, but might be nice to know for others. Anyway I got an answer how can I reduce the size at least a bit. Good enough for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've proposed keeping only HEAD which requires digging into internals of Git deeper than my knowledge allows to do comfortably.
Instead, I'll propose a few mostly non-destructive commands.

You may run `git prune`. This removes old parts on the local Git database, that are not used anymore. (For example, removed commits.) Normally Git keeps them for a longer time, just in case.

There is also `git gc` that does what `git prune` does and also a [whole lot of other things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141014/3052438) like repacking data so it takes less space.
This tends to reduce the size of the directory ".git" quite significantly, especially if you've been using the workspace for a long time without doing it.
You can add option `--aggressive` to increase the optimization at the cost of longer time to run the command.

If you really want to reduce the size of ".git" to minimum, you can call `git gc --agressive --prune=now` which removes absolutely all old object, regardless of their age. (Normally last few weeks are kept.) It should still be a safe thing to do in a local repository but I wouldn't do that without a good reason.

You can also get Git to remove ignored files from the workspace with the command `git clean -X`. These files are not showing in the output of `git status` so they may be more than you think. Just be careful to not delete your IDE configuration or something like that.

Comment: I aimed to get more or less the same amount of data as when using `git clone --depth 1`, but pruning should be good enough for me right now. Thx!